# Define global if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I'm trying to set a global if it doesnt exist. Total noob question.

I'm doing this:

```
if (!raw) {
   raw = 'yep';
}
```

But it keeps throwing reference error raw is not defined.

Comment: If you're getting a reference error then you are likely running in strict mode.

Comment: nope, he gets reference errors cause he doesn't "reference" raw before checking for it's value, if you wanna test for a vaiable if it exists you'd have to use "typeof raw == 'undefined'" or window.raw

Answer (score 2):

This is one way, assuming `window` exists:

```
if(!window.raw) {
  raw = 'yup';    
}
```

If not, you could just make a global object to use:

```
globals = {};

if(!globals.raw) {
  globals.raw = 'yup';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the global scope add:

```
var raw;
```